# How to group tuples by common items and find average per each group

Tags: python, list, tuples, average

I have a list of tuples named `data`:

```
data = [('A', 2), 
        ('B', 2), ('B', 4), ('B', 6), ('B', 8), ('B', 6), ('B', 4), ('B', 3),
        ('C', 10), ('C', 10), ('C', 10),
        ('D', 12),
        ('E', 12),
        ('F', 10), ('F', 8), ('F', 6)]
average = []
```

I would like an average of the values for each same letter:

Expected Output:

```
average = [('A', 2), ('B', 5), ('C', 10), ('D', 12), ('E', 12), ('F', 8)]
```

Comment: You should look at dictionaries rather than using tuples this way. They hold key/value pairs and let you find values for certain keys.

Comment: I made another array counting each letter count=[1,7,3,1,1,3] then for each 1 get the index and append it to the list, but for the rest of the numbers Im having a headache using the indexes... im new to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
data_ = [(n,[i[1] for i in g]) for n,g in groupby(data, key = lambda x:x[0])]   
result = [(i,float(sum(j))/float(len(j))) for i,j in data_]
```

**Result**

```
[('A', 2.0),
 ('B', 4.714285714285714),
 ('C', 10.0),
 ('D', 12.0),
 ('E', 12.0),
 ('F', 8.0)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option with a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
avg = defaultdict(lambda :{'count': 0, 'sum': 0})
​
# calculate the sum and count for each key
for k, v in data:
    avg[k]['count'] += 1
    avg[k]['sum'] += v

# calculate the average
[(k, v['sum']/v['count']) for k, v in avg.items()]

#[('A', 2.0),
# ('D', 12.0),
# ('F', 8.0),
# ('E', 12.0),
# ('B', 4.714285714285714),
# ('C', 10.0)]
```

Comment: Why the nested dict? Just store the numbers in a list and do `sum(v)/len(v)`

Comment: @tobias_k You will need extra space to store the numbers, and also, `sum/len` means a second loop is needed. I think calculation on the go should be more efficient.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution is more general than `itertools.groupby`, as it is O(n) without requiring the input to be pre-sorted.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative solution which you might consider, especially when dealing with large data sets, is to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Here, [`groupby` and `mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('A', 2), 
        ('B', 2), ('B', 4), ('B', 6), ('B', 8), ('B', 6), ('B', 4), ('B', 3),
        ('C', 10), ('C', 10), ('C', 10),
        ('D', 12),
        ('E', 12),
        ('F', 10), ('F', 8), ('F', 6)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['letter', 'number'])
print(df)
#    letter  number
# 0       A       2
# 1       B       2
# 2       B       4
# 3       B       6
# 4       B       8
# 5       B       6
# 6       B       4
# 7       B       3
# 8       C      10
# 9       C      10
# 10      C      10
# 11      D      12
# 12      E      12
# 13      F      10
# 14      F       8
# 15      F       6

print(df.groupby('letter').mean())
#            number
# letter           
# A        2.000000
# B        4.714286
# C       10.000000
# D       12.000000
# E       12.000000
# F        8.000000

print(df.groupby('letter').mean().round().astype(int))
#         number
# letter        
# A            2
# B            5
# C           10
# D           12
# E           12
# F            8
```

You can get back your list of tuples as follows:

```
averages = df.groupby('letter').mean().round().astype(int)
result = list(result.to_records())
print(result)
# [('A', 2), ('B', 5), ('C', 10), ('D', 12), ('E', 12), ('F', 8)]
```